# Is this proof that $AB=I$ implies $BA=I$ incorrect?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

I'm self-studying from Kenneth Kuttler's textbook *Linear Algebra, Theory, and Applications* and this proof on page 61 seems a little fishy. Specifically, I have a problem with the final section (last paragraph), where he tries to use the first part of the theorem

> A square matrix $A$ is onto iff $A$ is one to one

To show that

> For $n$x$n$ matrices $A$ and $B$, if $AB=I$ then $BA=I$.

Here is the proof:
[image: The problematic proof]

I am suspicious of his assertion that

> $B$ is one to one since otherwise there would exist $\bf{x}\not=\bf{0}$ such that $B\bf{x}=\bf{0}$.

Does the fact that the map is not 1-1 guarantee that every element in the range is the image of two non-identical elements, or did Kuttler make a mistake here? He has discussed vector spaces and subspaces, but has not mentioned any special vector spaces associated with a given matrix, and he has not discussed invertibility beyond mentioning that some matrices have inverses (and how to find them). He has also not discussed any iteration of the invertible matrix theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $B$ is not one to one then we can write $Bx = By$ for $x \neq y$.  But then $x - y \neq 0$ and $B(x - y) = 0$, so $B$ has a nonzero element in its nullspace.  Conversely, if there is a nonzero element in the nullspace, say $x \neq 0$ and $Bx = 0$, then for any $y$ we have $y \neq y + x$ and $By = B(x + y)$, so every element in the image has multiple preimages.